# bootstrap v3 - input field not hiding underneath the modal overlay

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3 modal, and when modal is shown, the overlay does not hide input fields behind it, that is, the input fields remain like they are on top. See screenshot below:

[image]

In the screenshot I've inspected and deleted the modal, but as you can see, the input fields do not seem to be behind the overlay. I checked with `z-index` it's not the case; the overlay is indeed above it. I'm using D3 to select and manipulate the text fields, is it because of that ? What might be causing this, and how to fix it ?

Comment: Please provide working fiddle or any link.

Comment: as @ankitapatel said, we need to see the code.

Comment: well this is inside a large Angular application, so what portion of the code would you want to see so that it becomes useful ? I wanted to know if there were any known conditions that may cause this

Comment: definitely the portion that related to the problem!

Comment: Portions of css, altering the behavior of input fields would be a good candidate.

Comment: the reason I didn't include any code was that there is no specific css that I have provided for the input field nor the modal. I'm manipulating those fields using D3 and that's it. I can include the html template code of the modal if you want, but that's all. I've not added any of my own styles to the modal. Don't know if it will be useful

Comment: just increased `.modal` class `z-index:9999` and check it...

Comment: @MinalChauhan no :(